# Iterate through Each Record In a Table with Non-identity column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to Iterate through Each Record In a `Table` and assign that `record` value to a `variable` using `while` loop. The table doesn't have any `Identity` or `sequence` column. I know that we can create a `temp table` with `table data` and `identity column` or `Rownumber` and use it for Each Record iteration. Is there any other way around to select `rownumber` for a particular record `implicitly` for each `row`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you any sample data? The answer is yes, you can use a cursor or something similiar, but I would revisit why you 'need' to do it this way... SQL is a better for set based operations. Iterating through record sets is better done in an application

Comment: we have around 1000 offices. for each office-id we have to execute a stored procedure to calculate the budget. I think looping is the only way around

Comment: Fair enough. I've added an answer that should do the job for you, or at least get you going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job. Inside the cursor you can do whatever you like with your variables, I've just passed them into a proc.

```
DECLARE @office_id AS int, @row_number AS INT
DECLARE c CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT  office_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY office_id order BY office_id) 
    FROM    my_office_table
    WHERE   offices_to_budget_for = 'Y'

OPEN c 
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @office_id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    EXEC dbo.do_budget_for_office @office_id, @row_number

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @office_id, @row_number
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

I really don't recommend cursors for everyday use, but they are a tool and have their place.

EDIT:

```
SELECT  office_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY office_id order BY office_id) as rowNum
into  #TempOffices
FROM    my_office_table
WHERE   offices_to_budget_for = 'Y'

While (Select Count(*) From #TempOffices) > 0
Begin

    Select Top 1 @office_id = office_id, @row_number = rowNumFrom #Temp

    --Do some processing here

    Delete #Temp Where Id = @Id and rowNum = @row_number

End

drop #tempOffices
```

You aren't really gaining anything by not using a cursor. It is designed for this sort of operation.

Again though, neither cursors OR while loops should be used in sql very often. Its like NOLOCK. Its a tool. Used incorrectly can cause a lot of damage. Used correctly and in the right circumstances they are a life saver.

Comment: I would rather use While Loop Instead of Cursor. Cursors are strictly prohibited in our workspace :(

Comment: A cursor and a while loop are functionally the same. Re-writing a cursor as a while loop doesn't make it OK, they are both doing the same thing, which arguably you shouldn't be doing in the database. They are the tool for what you are trying to do here. I've edit my answer to use a while loop though

Answer (score 1):

Use the window function `ROW_NUMBER` in your `SELECT` statement.  It provides a unique number for each row returned in the query.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: The problem is I have to put the Rowcount value in Where Clause too to fetch a particular record. I got syntax error while doing this